# Objective-C TCP Server with SSL / TLS support

Tags: objective-c, sockets, ssl, tcp, nsstream

I have a simple TCP Server / Client setup. This connection actually works great.

Now I wanted to implement SSL / TLS encryption for the socket connections. I created a PKCS12 certificate using keychain access. In my server I have the following code inside the accept callback:

```
NSString *certificatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TCPServerCertificate" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:certificatePath];

CFArrayRef keyRef;
OSStatus status = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)certificateData, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{(__bridge NSString *)kSecImportExportPassphrase: @"1234"}, &keyRef);

if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"PKCS12 import error %i", status);
    return;
}

CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(keyRef, 0);
SecIdentityRef identityRef = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);

SecCertificateRef certificate;
status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef, &certificate);

if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"sec identity copy failed: %i", status);
    return;
}

NSArray *certificates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)identityRef, (__bridge id)certificate, nil];

NSDictionary *settings = @{(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket:    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain:       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates:       [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots:              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot:                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates:                    certificates,
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLIsServer:                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLLevel:                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1};

CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
```

Then I create `NSStream` instances of the streams and handle them in another class.

When I run the server and connect a client, I'm getting the regular `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted` in my delegate. When I then try to write to the stream or event if I just close the connection, I'm getting the following errors:

```
2013-10-25 13:27:08.584 TCPServer[6435:303] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9800)
2013-10-25 13:27:08.584 TCPServer[6435:303] NSStreamEventOpenCompleted
2013-10-25 13:27:08.585 TCPServer[6435:303] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred
```

I wonder what I have to implement on the client side. Also I wonder why I'm getting the handshake failure when sending data or disconnecting from the client side. Whenever this error occurs, the client thinks it's still connected.

Are there any good TCP SSL/TLS tutorials or other material that covers both, the client and the server side?

Comment: Are you using this same code on both ends of the connection?  If so, then it looks like you are setting the `kCFStreamSSLIsServer` property to `YES` on both sides of the connection.

Comment: I'm not in office at the moment. But it might be right. Should I then just remove the `kCFStreamSSLIsServer`?

Comment: I think you'd want to keep this line of code - on the side of the connection that is the server, leave it as is.  But on the client side, you'll want to set this value to `NO` in the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure now. I did several TCP test and edu projects… But I think you should just give it a shot, when you'r struggling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with this code:
You can not set kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket with kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, and you should not mix server and client code.

For server you should just set a certificate

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty(read, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(write, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
//kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel
//Note: If you set this key, you must do so before setting any other SSL options, such as kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings.
CFReadStreamSetProperty(read, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(write, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
//Creating server dictionnary

//kCFStreamSSLIsServer
//If the value of this key is kCFBooleanTrue, the kCFStreamSSLCertificates key must contain a valid value

//kCFStreamSSLCertificates
//Security property key whose value is a CFArray of SecCertificateRefs except for the first element in the array, which is a SecIdentityRef.
//For more information, see SSLSetCertificate() in Security/SecureTransport.h.

NSDictionary *settings = @{(id)kCFStreamSSLCertificates:                    certificates,
                           (id)kCFStreamSSLIsServer:                        @YES};


//Apply settings
CFReadStreamSetProperty(read, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(settings));
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(write, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(settings));
```

For client if you want to override the validation chain ([See Apple doc on overriding chain validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html)) you should do the following:

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty(read, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(write, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
//kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel
//Note: If you set this key, you must do so before setting any other SSL options, such as kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings.

CFReadStreamSetProperty(read, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(write, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);

//DO NOT USE kCFStreamPropertySSLContext as it overrides the following configuration
//create dictionnary for kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings

//keys for dictionnary we want to change:kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates;kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots;kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot;
//kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain => no need to worry about the root
//kCFStreamSSLPeerName kCFNull prevents name verification


settings = @{(id)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: @NO,//The delegate will verify this
             (id)kCFStreamSSLPeerName: (id)kCFNull};//prevents name verification if server is not fixed (eg. IP)

//Apply settings
CFReadStreamSetProperty(read, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(settings));
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(write, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(settings));
```

Comment: Could you explain why I have to set `kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket`?

Comment: kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket will close the connection at the end of the object's life. Otherwise you have to manually close the native socket.

Comment: Thanks for your help back then. You got me up and running, even though the properties for preventing chain verification got deprecated / replaced. Let's go for a follow-up question about 7 years later :D I want to enforce TLS but seem to fall back to SSL. `kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1` results in an SSL protocol error... Have you got a quick tip?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a package that makes TLS/TCP easier with the new iOS 13 restrictions. Hope it helps someone! Feel free to contribute:

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets